# I touched a CRT television monitor and have some feelings in my hand.what is the reason?

Tags: electrostatics

It felt like some sort of vibration. Even though when I unplugged the power cable it is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Static electricity stored on the glass.

Comment: Does static electric cause a vibratory sensation?

Comment: Probably a little more complicated than just "stored on the glass".  The _inside_ of the glass is bombarded by electrons when the CRT is operating.  Some of those remain on the inside surface after the device is switched off.  Electrons on the outer surface want to flee the vicinity, but they have nowhere to go until the OP brings a hand near, at which point, the electrons leap to the OP's hand (OP feels tingly "vibration"), and the outer surface becomes, positively charged.  (The process historically is known as _charging by induction_.)